# how to run an external script from a Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to run an external script from my RoR app, within my controller (by passing a boolean parameter) :

```
 if (:run)
system(Dir.pwd+'\test.sh')
flash[:error] = "Script Running"
 end
```

2 options here :

- best one : we can run it anywhere on the filesystem **/etc/myscripts/test.sh** or **C:\scripts\test.sh**
- worst one : I can run it from the **/var/www/myapp/scripts/test.sh** folder

any ideas ? thanks

Comment: [File#join](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/File.html#method-c-join) will help with choosing the correct slash.

Comment: Your if condition will always be true because you're giving it a symbol.

Comment: my param is sometimes false Diego